# Elapsed time of coroutines/futures using asyncio.gather()

Tags: python, asynchronous, query-optimization, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have a list of async queries which I'm gathering with `asyncio.gather()` & waiting with `asyncio.run_until_complete()`. Something like:

```
queries = [
  async_query_a(),
  async_query_b()
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = asyncio.gather(*queries)
results = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

I would like to know the "waiting time" of each of the queries. Something like a @log_performance wrapper which logs the elapsed time of the future/coroutine completion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example implementation of `timecoro` timeing a coroutine function.

```py
import asyncio
import functools
import logging
import random
import time

def timecoro(corofn):
    @functools.wraps(corofn)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            result = await corofn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            finish = time.time() - start
            logging.info('%s failed in %.2f', corofn, finish)
            raise
        else:
            finish = time.time() - start
            logging.info('%s succeeded in %.2f', corofn, finish)
            return result            
        
    return wrapper

@timecoro
async def async_query_a():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 4))

@timecoro    
async def async_query_b():
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 4))
    raise RuntimeError

async def main():
    queries = [
        async_query_a(),
        async_query_b(),
    ]
    await asyncio.gather(*queries)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level='INFO')
    asyncio.run(main())
```